# How can I access state of another slice in redux with redux-toolkit?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

In my Redux store I have multiple slices and I would like to access the `lang` state of the settingsSlice inside the speciesSlice.

Here is a code sample of my slices:

```js
const settingsSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'settings',
  initialState: { lang: 'en', theme: 'dark' },
  reducers: {
    ...
  },
});

const speciesSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'species',
  initialState: data[`vds-list-${HERE I WANT TO USE THE "lang" STATE OF THE SETTINGSSLICE}`],
  reducers: {
    ...
  },
});
```

Thus far I haven't found a solution so maybe it's just not possible?

I could just use one slice with all of the state inside of there, but I'd really like to separate different parts of the state in different slices.

Comment: If you only use the settings default state then why not define `{ lang: 'en', theme: 'dark' }` as a constant and use that constant?

Comment: @HMR the state of the settingsSlice changes over time. It adapts to the users system language or the overridden setting.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Reducers, by definition, only have access to the section of state that they own.  So, if I have `{users: usersReducer, posts: postsReducer}`, the `usersReducer` has no access to the `posts` state slice at all.

See [the Redux FAQ entry on "how can I share state between reducers?"](https://redux.js.org/faq/reducers#how-do-i-share-state-between-two-reducers-do-i-have-to-use-combinereducers) for more details.

Answer (score 11):

I've managed to achieve this by simply importing the redux store object and have called `getState()` method.

so in `speciesSlice` reducer action you can do that:

```
const speciesSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'species',
  initialState: data[`vds-list-${HERE I WANT TO USE THE "lang" STATE OF THE SETTINGSSLICE}`],
  reducers: {
    ...
    setLang: (state, _) => {
      const reduxStore = store.getState();
      const lang = reduxStore.settingsSlice.lang;
      state = data[`vds-list-${lang}`];
    },
    ...
  },
});
```

Comment: Would this be considered bad practice / anti pattern?

Comment: @DrorBar No, I guess not, there are multiple mentions of the same methodology in redux documentations as well

Comment: @Dror Personally I would consider it an anti-pattern to avoid.  It seems like the reducer in this example doesn’t really do anything and can easily be replaced with a selector (that selects the active language and returns the corresponding data).

Comment: @BiskremMuhammad Could you cite/link to the part of the documentation where importing a store and working with it directly is mentioned

Comment: @GabrielPetersson.. here is the [api reference](https://redux.js.org/api/store#getState), see the examples.

Comment: @BiskremMuhammad it's an example for how selectors work, nowhere do they recommend importing the store into your reducer https://redux.js.org/faq/reducers#how-do-i-share-state-between-two-reducers-do-i-have-to-use-combinereducers

Comment: This does not work, I get the error "You may not call store.getState() while the reducer is executing. The reducer has already received the state as an argument. Pass it down from the top reducer instead of reading it from the store."

Comment: **You _cannot_ and _must not_ import the store into a reducer file, or try to call `store.getState()` in a reducer!**  This is explicitly forbidden and will throw an error.

Answer (score 7):

We can do it by [adding `extraReducers` to respond to the `action`](https://redux.js.org/style-guide/#allow-many-reducers-to-respond-to-the-same-action)

```js
// Slice A - sliceA.js
export const sliceAinitialState = {
  lang: 'en',
}
const sliceA = createSlice({
  name: 'A'
  initialSlice: sliceAinitialState,
  reducers: {
    langChangedAtSliceA: (state, action) => state.lang = action.payload,
  }
})
export const {langChangedAtSliceA } = sliceA.actions

// Slice B - sliceB.js
import {sliceAinitialState, langChangedAtSliceA} from 'sliceA.js'
const sliceB = createSlice({
  name: 'B'
  initialSlice: {
    lang: sliceAinitialState.lang
  },
  extraReducers: (builder) => {
    builder.addCase(langChangedAtSliceA, (state, action) => {
      state.lang = action.payload
    })
  }
})
```

Answer (score 3):

As referenced in the Redux FAQ entry, ["How do I share state between two reducers?"](https://redux.js.org/faq/reducers#how-do-i-share-state-between-two-reducers-do-i-have-to-use-combinereducers), you can use [redux-thunk](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk) to write a reducer that can access the entire state. For example:

```js
const speciesSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'species',
  initialState: data[`vds-list-${HERE I WANT TO USE THE "lang" STATE OF THE SETTINGSSLICE}`],
  reducers: {
    ...
    internalSetLang: (state, action) => {
      state = data[`vds-list-${action.payload}`];
    },
    ...
  },
});

const { internalSetLang } = speciesSlice.actions;

export function setLang() {
  return (dispatch, getState) => {
    const lang = getState().settings.lang;
    dispatch(internalSetLang(lang));
  };
}
```

This is similar to @Biskrem Muhammad's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71744321/25507) but avoids having to use the Redux store as a global variable.

Answer (score 0):

There is a specific [createDraftSafeSelector](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createSelector) function available in redux-toolkit for that usage.

Answer (score 0):

It is not necessary to hard code.
If you want to use a data from X slice in Y slice, all you have to do is export the initial state of X slice and import it in Y slice, so that whenever the X slice state changes, it will automatically change it in Y slice also.

Comment: Please elaborate. Try for [answer].

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).