# Cascade deletion trough multiple Redux Slices / entityAdapters

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, redux-toolkit

I'm currently using multiple Entity Adapters and slices to manage my Redux's store, in which the models have relationships between them. I'm using a listening middleware to cascade deletions between these models, but I'm failing to actually cascade from the top to bottom.

As a simple example, imagine an Author, a Book (that has an author), and a Page (that has a book). This would be a simple definition for them:

```
// authorsSlice.ts
type Author = { id: EntiyId };
const authorsAdapter = createEntityAdapter<Author>();
const authorsSlice = createSlice({
  name:" author",
  reducers: {
    deleteAuthor: authorsAdapter.removeOne
  }
});
const authorsActions = authorsSlice.actions;

// booksSlice.ts
type Book = { id: EntiyId, authorId: EntityId };
const booksAdapter = createEntityAdapter<Book>();
const booksSlice = createSlice({
  name:" books",
  reducers: {
    deleteBook: booksAdapter.removeOne,
    cascadeDeleteAuthor: (state, action: PayloadAction<EntityId>) => {
      const { authorId } = action.payload;
      const toRemove = booksAdapter.getSelectors()
        .selectAll(state)
        .filter((book) => book.authorId === authorId)
        .map((book) => book.id)
      booksAdapter.removeMany(state, toRemove);
    }
  }
});
const booksActions = booksSlice.actions;

// pagesSlice.ts
type Page = { id: EntityAdapter, bookId: EntityId };
const pagesAdapter = createEntityAdapter<Book>();
const pagesSlice = createSlice({
  name:" pages",
  reducers: {
    deleteBook: pagesAdapter.removeOne,
    cascadeDeleteBook: (state, action: PayloadAction<EntityId>) => {
      const { bookId } = action.payload;
      const toRemove = pagesAdapter.getSelectors()
        .selectAll(state)
        .filter((page) => page.bookId === bookId)
        .map((page) => page.id)
      pagesAdapter.removeMany(state, toRemove);
    }
  }
});
const pagesActions = pagesSlice.actions;
```

Now, to cascade the deletion of them I have a listener middleware applied to the store, and have started listening to the delete actions:

```
startListening({
  actionCreator: authorsActions.deleteAuthor,
  effect: async (action, listenerApi) => {
    listenerApi.dispatch(
      booksActions.cascadeDeleteAuthor(action.payload),
    );
  },
});
startListening({
  actionCreator: booksActions.deleteBook,
  effect: async (action, listenerApi) => {
    listenerApi.dispatch(
      pagesActions.cascadeDeleteBook(action.payload),
    );
  },
});
```

Which works well... except it fails to cascade from Author -> Page. It's clear why - when a Book is deleted by cascade, the "deleteBooK" action is **not** dispatched, so the page listener doesn't catch it. I'm failing to come up with a way to achieve this (Making it so that deleting an author -> deletes their books -> deletes their pages).

I've tried to add aditional listeners to listen to the `cascadeDelete` actions; the issue is that the payload that comes with them is an Id that the model doesn't know about (the pages listening to the `cascadeDeleteAuthor` action would only get the Author Id, and they only hold a reference to the book and not the author). It could technically be done by accessing the entire store inside the slice ([SO Answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62451320/)), but that doesn't seem like the optimal way to do it. Holding the reference to the author in the pages also seems like an overtly complicated solution, having to break out of the relationship models. I've also looked into getting a return value from dispatch (with `asyncThunk`s), but from my understanding I can't achieve this behaviour with them.

So, to pose the question summed up:

- How can I "cascade delete" entities that have more than 1 relationship level between them in Redux?